# Plotly 3-D surface/contour plots of a function at different depths in the cartesian domain

Tags: plotly, surface

I’m relatively new to plotly and it looks like an amazing tool to me! However, as a new user, I am also running into a series of issue that I hope you could help me with.

In short, I’m using plotly for the post-processing analysis of the vorticity field of my 3d simulations. This means that I have my X-Y-Z coordinates and a function W which values exist at each grid point in the 3-D space but they are not the same of Z. Let's say X goes from -2000 to 2000, Y from -1500 to 1500, Z from 0 to -660 and W from -10 to +10.

I'd like to visualise the value of W at different XY plans of equal depth (e.g. 0km, -110km and -660km). If being Z*= a constant depth value, I do (W - Z*), this shifts the surface plot to the right depth. However, the  value of the function W changes as well into (W-Z*) and it has since NO physical meaning.

Below there's a vanilla example that reproduces this.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

# Create 3D grid
X      =        np.linspace(-2000, 2000, 15)
Y      =        np.linspace(-1500, 1500, 6)
Z      =        np.linspace(-660, 0., 6)

x, y, z = np.meshgrid(X, Y, Z, indexing='ij')

assert np.all(x[:,0,0] == X)
assert np.all(y[0,:,0] == Y)
assert np.all(z[0,0,:] == Z)


w1 = np.array([
    [8.83,8.89,8.81,8.87,8.9,8.87],
    [8.89,8.94,8.85,8.94,8.96,8.92],
    [8.84,8.9,8.82,8.92,8.93,8.91],
    [8.79,8.85,8.79,8.9,8.94,8.92],
    [8.79,8.88,8.81,8.9,8.95,8.92],
    [8.8,8.82,8.78,8.91,8.94,8.92],
    [8.75,8.78,8.77,8.91,8.95,8.92],
    [8.8,8.8,8.77,8.91,8.95,8.94],
    [8.74,8.81,8.76,8.93,8.98,8.99],
    [8.89,8.99,8.92,9.1,9.13,9.11],
    [8.97,8.97,8.91,9.09,9.11,9.11],
    [9.04,9.08,9.05,9.25,9.28,9.27],
    [9,9.01,9,9.2,9.23,9.2],
    [8.99,8.99,8.98,9.18,9.2,9.19],
    [8.93,8.97,8.97,9.18,9.2,9.18]
])
w2 = np.array([
    [8.83,8.89,8.81,8.87,8.9,8.87],
    [8.89,8.94,8.85,8.94,8.96,8.92],
    [8.84,8.9,8.82,8.92,8.93,8.91],
    [8.79,8.85,8.79,8.9,8.94,8.92],
    [8.79,8.88,8.81,8.9,8.95,8.92],
    [8.8,8.82,8.78,8.91,8.94,8.92],
    [8.75,8.78,8.77,8.91,8.95,8.92],
    [8.8,8.5,8.77,8.91,8.95,8.94],
    [8.74,8.81,8.76,8.93,4.98,8.99],
    [8.89,8.99,8.92,9.1,9.13,9.11],
    [8.97,8.97,8.91,9.09,9.11,9.11],
    [9.04,9.08,9.05,9.25,9.28,9.27],
    [9,9.01,16,9.2,9.23,9.2],
    [8.99,8.99,8.98,9.18,9.2,9.19],
    [8.93,8.97,8.97,9.18,9.2,9.18]
])
w3 = np.array([
    [8.83,8.89,8.81,8.87,8.9,8.87],
    [8.89,8.94,8.85,8.94,8.96,8.92],
    [8.84,8.9,8.82,8.92,8.93,8.91],
    [8.79,8.85,8.79,8.9,4.94,8.92],
    [8.79,8.88,8.81,8.9,8.95,8.92],
    [8.8,8.82,8.78,8.91,8.94,8.92],
    [8.75,8.78,8.77,8.91,8.95,8.92],
    [8.8,8.8,8.77,8.91,8.95,8.94],
    [8.74,8.81,8.76,8.93,8.98,8.99],
    [8.89,8.99,8.92,9.1,9.13,9.11],
    [8.97,8.97,8.91,9.09,9.11,9.11],
    [9.04,9.08,20.05,9.25,9.28,9.27],
    [9,9.01,9,9.2,9.23,9.2],
    [8.99,8.99,8.98,9.18,9.2,9.19],
    [8.93,8.97,8.97,9.18,9.2,9.18]
])

w2 = w2 -110 
w3 = w3 - 660


mycolorscale = [[0, 'magenta'],[0.3, 'violet'], [0.35, 'blue'], [0.5, 'green'],[0.6, 'yellow'],[0.8, 'orange'], [1, 'red']]


fig1 = go.Figure(data=[
        go.Surface (


            z=w1, showscale=False,opacity=0.9,),

        go.Surface(

                   z=w2,showscale=False, opacity=0.9,),
        go.Surface(

                   z=w3,  opacity=0.9,),  ])

fig1.update_layout(coloraxis = dict(colorscale=mycolorscale, cmin =-320, cmax=320, colorbar_thickness=25))




fig1.update_layout(scene = dict(
                    xaxis_title='X [km]',
                    yaxis_title='Y [km]',
                    zaxis_title='Z [km]'),
                    )




fig1.show()
```

This is the output and how you can see the colours of the plane are a way below the min value of w:
[image: img1]

Here, you can find a extended version of this query: https://community.plot.ly/t/plot-different-3d-surface-contour-plot-planes-of-the-same-function-at-different-depths-in-the-cartesian-domain/32933/5

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I was able (with some external help) to reproduce this with a plotly isosurface plot as for figure and code attached below. However, as I'm dealing with an HR 3D simulation it becomes very computationally expensive for me to load the entire  F(x, y, z) at each time step, and I would like to achieve the same result just by plotting 3 different surface plots at the appropriate depth. I still don't know how to achieve that.

```
'' # Create 3D grid
X      =        np.linspace(-2000., 2000.,xRes+1)
Y      =        np.linspace(-1500., 1500., zRes+1)
Z      =        np.linspace(-660., 0., yRes+1)
x, y, z = np.meshgrid(X, Y, Z, indexing='ij')

A = np.arange(1085825)  #generating example data
B = np.reshape(A,(257,65,65))   
C = B[:,:,0]

import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

mycolorscale = [[0, 'magenta'],[0.3, 'violet'], [0.35, 'blue'], [0.5, 'green'],[0.6, 'yellow'],[0.8, 'orange'], [1, 'red']]


fig1 = go.Figure(data=go.Isosurface(   
 x=x.flatten(),
 y=y.flatten(),
 z=z.flatten(),
 value=B.flatten(),
 #isomin=0,
 #isomax=50,
 #surface_fill=0.4,
 opacity=0.6,
 coloraxis='coloraxis',
 caps=dict(x_show=False, y_show=False),
 slices_z=dict(show=True, locations=[0, -110]),
 #slices_y=dict(show=True, locations=[-2000]),
))

# define your plot ennv
fig1.update_layout(coloraxis = dict(colorscale=mycolorscale, cmin =-320, cmax=320, colorbar_thickness=25))

fig1.update_layout(
 margin=dict(t=0, l=0, b=0), # tight layout
 scene_camera_eye=dict(x=1.86, y=0.61, z=0.98))
fig1.show() ''
```

[image: Realtive output:]